# Implement MirrorLink on Custom ROM - Android

Tags: android, apk, rom, mirrorlink

Can we implement MirrorLink on Android devices which are not currently supported? I'm currently using OnePlus Two but it doesn't support MirrorLink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be a fully MirrorLink 1.1 capable phone it has to be certified by the Car Connectivity Consortium.

This includes implementing a function called device attestation protocol (DAP). This ensures the validity of the MirrorLink capable phone against the MirrorLink capable vehicle. This is implemented to make sure the device will only send content/applications which are safe to use while driving.

So unfortunately the manufacturer of the phone has to implement MirrorLink, no weekend coding fun for normal users. 
Let me know how OnePlus replies to your feature request.

If you would like to implement MirrorLink in the so called 1.0 version it would be possible to do it, I guess. This version has not the requirement of DAP. But this implementation would not be useable while driving in any cars (as far as I know).